# Can lego EV3 brick be programmed to get user input?

Tags: lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3, robotc

Sorry I am totally new to Lego ev3 Mindstorms, I need to do this for a subject's project.

I am going to program it using ROBOTC language, and to meet my project requirements I am thinking to allow user to enter input to the robot using the EV3 brick. Is it possible to do so? If possible how can I do it?

Lastly may I get some online guides to ROBOTC programming for Lego EV3 mindstorms?

Sorry for asking so many questions :(

Any help is much appreciated! :)
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to input something would be through the ev3 buttons or connected sensores. So if you want to input text, you could either use an onscreen keyboard or you build a hardware LEGO keyboard with various sensors. 
As for documentation, take a look at
http://help.robotc.net/WebHelpMindstorms/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ROBOTC but the ev3 has 6 buttons and a display. With alternative firmware like ev3dev.org you can program a dialog (to e.g. ask for a value) and enter this using the 6 buttons and an on-screen keyboard.